# 4 columns in java from two different loops

Tags: java, multiple-columns

I need help joining the 4 columns together, I have trying for hours and dont have any more ideas:

```
Celsius Fahrenheit | Fahrenheit Celsius
40.0 104.0 | 120.0 48.89
39.0 102.2 | 110.0 43.33
...
32.0 89.6 | 40.0 4.44
31.0 87.8 | 30.0 -1.11
```

here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for ( double x = 40; x >= 31; x--){
        System.out.printf("%10.1f%10.1f\n",  x, celsiusToFahrenheit(x));
    }

    for ( double y = 120; y >= 30; y -= 10){
        System.out.printf("%-10.1f%-5.1f\n", y, fahrenheitToCelsius(y));
    }

}

public static double celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius){
    return (9.0/5) * celsius + 32;
}

public static double fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit){
    return (5.0 / 9) * (fahrenheit - 32);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'Joining' them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by combining these values. Try something like this,

```
    for ( double x = 40,  y=120; x >= 31; x--, y-=10){
        System.out.printf("%10.1f%10.1f",  x, celsiusToFahrenheit(x));
        System.out.printf("%10.1f%10.1f\n", y, fahrenheitToCelsius(y));
    }
```

This may be the most concise way of combining results, feel free to add more robust loop termination condition

Comment: Thank you very much Kamoor1982, it is simple and does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use your first loop to build a `String` array and then print it with your second. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[40 - 30];
    int i = 0;
    for (double x = 40; x >= 31; x--) {
        arr[i++] = String.format("%10.1f%10.1f", x,
                celsiusToFahrenheit(x));
    }
    i = 0;
    for (double y = 120; y >= 30; y -= 10) {
        System.out.printf("%s\t %-10.1f%-5.1f%n", arr[i++], y,
                fahrenheitToCelsius(y));
    }
}
```

Output is

```
  40.0     104.0     120.0     48.9
```

...

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using a `ArrayList<StringBuilder>` combination? Or `Vector<StringBuffer>` (if it needs to be thread safe).

Basically build your output first, then display the results when done.

Comment: How have you been able to provide an answer to such an ambiguous question?

Comment: Maybe my assumption is wrong, but I'm guessing Homedad wants the _row_ output from both loops to be on the same _line_

Comment: And don't use `Vector`, because most likely you won't need it to be thread safe. A `List` or `Collection` would be a more appropriate advice in my opinion. Same goes for `StringBuffer` (would advice `StringBuilder` instead).

Comment: @bali182, the code is written inside a static main, so who cares? If you want to assume speed is important, that's fine, but don't ignore that fact that others might care about being thread safe, even if you don't!

Comment: I don't know how much OP knows Java, but most likely doesn't have so much experience with it as you. So if he/she takes the Vector/StringBuffer idea, and starts using it extensively in a real app, where performance could count, then he/she could cause some serious refactoring material for his/her later self. Don't take my advice as offense, it was an advice, which in my opinion is completely justified.

Comment: @bali182, and exactly the same amount refactoring + a hell of a lot of debugging is required to make it thread safe if that becomes an issue!